# What will beautiful girls be accountable for during hasab on account of their beauty?

Tags: women

I ask out of curiosity; every human must account for every neamat Allah (sut) has given e.g. For each hand, what good have you done by this hand? For the tongue, what good has it uttered?

What will beautiful girls be accountable for?

Answer (score 2):

Women will be asked in what ways they used their beauty.

Did they use it in Halal ways, for example to please their husbands (which is a good deed in itself) OR did they use their beauty in Haram ways such as to show off, seduce, etc.

It's well known that the concept of *Tabarruj* (display of beauty) is one that is of disobedience to Allah (ﷻ). Allah (ﷻ) said to conceal our beauty except from deserving eyes, namely the husband.

> ..do not display yourselves as [was] the display of the former times of ignorance.. (33:33).

Beauty is a trial for some women, who fall into society's traps and proceed to use their beauty in incorrect ways. So again, the way in which they used their beauty on earth will be addressed.